# Use .htaccess to block *All* access to specific folders

Tags: security, .htaccess, blocking

I am not sure how to do this, but I want to block all access to a specific set of folders on my web server. Say secret01 and secret 02...

```
homeDir
  |- data
  |- www
  |   |- .htaccess (file)
  |   |- images
  |   |- js
  |   |- secret01
  |   |- secret02
  |   |...
  |...
```

What rule(s) do I need to add to my root .htaccess file to do this? I want all access from the web blocked from going into these folders, period. Only way one could get to them would be over `SFTP` or `SSH`. So what rule am I looking for? I am preferably looking for a one-liner so I can add more folders or move it to another site down the road. I really would prefer if the rule could be placed in the .htaccess root file so I don't have to jump all over the place to lock and unlock folders.

= Update for Clarity =

I do not have access to the conf file for this host (it is in a shared environment) and I need to have these folders inside the webroot for a few shell purposes. If I could I would have already moved them up out of the webroot.

I also don't want to screw with the file permissions, just have a rule in my `.htaccess` that blocks web traffic from accessing a folder or set of folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just create a .htaccess with

```
DENY FROM ALL
```

for the folders (put the file it in those).

Also with mod_rewrite on www/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(secret1|secret2|asdf) - [F,L]
```

Comment: Bam, I wanted that last line right there, I have no issue adding many folders to the rule, but that blocks out everything, ends rule checking, and prevents all access from the web. Great answer! Welcome to ServerFault :)

Answer (score 1):

If you truly do not want them accessible to the Internet via HTTP, you should move them outside of the Web tree entirely.

You can also use filesystem permissions.  For example, if Apache runs as the `apache` user, but you want the files only accessible via SSH by `user23` you can have secret* owned by `user2` and not publicly readable.  Of course, there are nearly endless additional options here.  Groups, filesystem ACLs, and more.

For ACLs, you can use mod_authz.  It's best to keep the configuration in the conf and not in `.htaccess`.  Having them in `.htaccess` introduces more exposure and possible for manipulation with lesser privileges.

[mod_authz documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html)

Comment: I understand that, but I need them in the webroot for shell purposes. I just want all access to them blocked from the outside world from the web. I *do not* have access to the conf file as this is a shared environment.

Comment: As handfix said, `deny from all` is all it takes.